# combine two array according to key position

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays.

```
array1 = {0=>{name=>'anju',addr=>'kottayam'},1=>{name=>'anu',addr=>'kochi'}}
```

and

```
array2 = {0=>{place=>'south',state=>'kerala'},1=>{place=>'north',state=>'andra'}}
```

I want to combine these two arrays such that 
The resulted array should be

```
array3 ={0=>{name=>'anju',addr=>'kottayam',place=>'south',state=>'kerala'},1=>{name=>'anu',addr=>'kochi',place=>'north',state=>'andra'}}
```

ie combine arrays on same key positions together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way could be

`$a3 = array_map("array_merge",$a1, $a2));`

Answer (score 0):

Without trying I would say:

`$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);`

Or

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value)
{
    $array3 = array_merge($array1[$key], $array2[$key]); // You should ask first if isset($array2[$key])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$size1 = sizeof($array1);
$size2 = sizeof($array2);

$cnt = $size1;
if($size2>$size1)
{
     $cnt = $size2;
}

$array3 = array();

for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++)
{
    if(isset($array1[$i])
    {
       $array3[$i] = $array1[$i];
    } 

    if(isset($array2[$i])
    {
       $array3[$i] = $array2[$i];
    } 
}
```

**METHOD : 2**

```
$size1 = sizeof($array1);
$size2 = sizeof($array2);

$array3 = array();
if($size2>$size1)
{
    $array3 = $array2;
    foreach($array1 as $key=>$arr)
    {
        $array3[$key] = $arr;
    }
}
else
{
    $array3 = $array1;
    foreach($array2 as $key=>$arr)
    {
        $array3[$key] = $arr;
    }
}
```